# What is the reverse of the 'go to next' command

Tags: search

If I want to go to the next `,` on the line then I type `t,`. If I wanted to go to the previous `,` I could use `/n`, enter, `N` but this is a bit of a fiddle. What is the best way to go to reverse the `t` command and go to the previous `,`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can just use `T,` and `F,` instead of `t,` and `f,`. The lowercase commands go forward; the uppercase ones go backwards.

**Example**:

```
foo, b|ar, baz
```

With the cursor on the first `a`, `t,` would move forward to `r` (the character before the next comma). Now if you use `T,` you will go backwards to the character after the previous comma (i.e. the space after `foo,`).

`f` and `F` do the same except they go to the specified character and not the character before/after it.

Also note you can use the `;` and `,` commands to repeat the last `f`, `F`, `t` or `T` command either in a forward of backwards direction.

For more on this read `:help f`.

Answer (score 10):

Just scroll down one paragraph in the help from `:help t` to find `T`, which moves

> Till after [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the left.

See also `:help F` which is to `f` what `T` is to `t`.

You can repeat the `fFtT` motions with `;` and also repeat in reverse direction with `,`, so if you are already moving forward through the `,`s on the line with `t,` and `;` to repeat, then want to move back, just hit `,` to repeat the `t` motion as if it was a `T` motion.